# Webpack dist folder not able to run the project

Tags: reactjs

I had created a React app using npm init and used webpack.
Project is running successfully and able to work integrated with Express JS also.
I had created dist folder using the command npm run build which created bundle.js file along with the index.html file.
When I try to open index.html file in chrome browser nothing gets displayed except header and footer, no error in console.

I expect the login form which is my application's home page to load when i open index.html file chrome browser.

Comment: How are you opening the index.html file? Do not open it as a file (so: no `file:///` in the browser URL) but use a web server.
Just a simple `python -m http.server` is enough

Comment: @keul : I had placed the dist folder contents inside Windows server 2012 and created an application in IIS. Am accessing website which is running from IIS in the browser. Am able to view header and footer but not loading the form content. No errors in the console.

Comment: Apart errors in the console: do you see resource loaded in the network tab?

Comment: No, Network tab is empty. I don't have any network or service call in my application on home page load.

Comment: Hard to say what's going on. I can only suggest you to put some `console.log()` inside the application entry point, just to understand if it's React that is not run, or the whole JS.
I can't say